# Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Python/django app (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, django, deployment, heroku, python-2.7

I'm doing the Heroku walkthrough: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#prerequisites for python developers, and I get an error when trying to run "git push heroku master", which can be found under the "Deploy to Heroku" section about 1/3 of the way down the page. I get the following traceback:

```
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 3.71 KiB, done.
Total 11 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
-----> Python/Django app detected
-----> Preparing Python interpreter (2.7.2)
-----> Creating Virtualenv (1.8.4)
       Also creating executable in .heroku/venv/bin/python
       Installing distribute...done.
       Installing pip...done.
       Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python2.7
-----> Installing dependencies using pip (1.1)
       Exception:
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/tmp/build_21leaqqhryfxe/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py",
line 104, in main
           status = self.run(options, args)
         File "/tmp/build_21leaqqhryfxe/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.
py", line 219, in run
           for req in parse_requirements(filename, finder=finder, options=options):
         File "/tmp/build_21leaqqhryfxe/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 128
8, in parse_requirements
           req = InstallRequirement.from_line(line, comes_from)
         File "/tmp/build_21leaqqhryfxe/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 85,
 in from_line
           elif os.path.isdir(path) and (os.path.sep in name or name.startswith('.')):
         File "/tmp/build_21leaqqhryfxe/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 41, in isdir
           st = os.stat(s)
       TypeError: must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str

       Storing complete log in /app/.pip/pip.log
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Python/django app

To git@heroku.com:stark-fortress-9694.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:stark-fortress-9694.git'
```

Everything else had worked successfully to this point. Any insight? I'm completely new to this. Thanks for any help in advance.

Here is what requirements.txt looks like:

```
Django==1.4.3
distribute==0.6.31
dj-database-url==0.2.1
psycopg2==2.4.5
```

Comment: Seems like one of your requirements is failing to install. Could you provide your requirements.txt file?

Comment: 1.  Have you run it locally?
2.  Have you run it through a linting tool?  
3.  What sort of test coverage do you have going so far?

Comment: I added Django tag, to bee seen by Django people too ..

Comment: I edited above to include requirements.txt

Comment: bitcycle... I have run it locally, and I do not know about your other two questions to be honest. Sorry, this is my first project ever worked on (no experience with server ever), just started learning programming a few months ago (learnpythonthehardway.org -> django book ->My own project), self-taught and still not really good. Sorry I can't be of more help for my own question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the problem is in the encoding of your `requirements.txt` file. Probably, you unknowingly saved it in Unicode format. You should save it in ANSI format. See this link for more details: http://georgik.sinusgear.com/2012/08/20/problems-with-deploying-heroku-django-app-from-windows/

Comment: I didn't have a problem in my encoding, but I had a package installed from a GitHub repository, and its line in `requirements.txt` was throwing the error.

Comment: It solved it for me too. Tip: don't forget to commit again after this fix, I was sure it didn't work because I was pushing without committing the fixed file :)