# My python app will not build when I try deploying to Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I'm having a hard time deploying my python app on heroku.

I'm doing automatic deployment from a github repo

my Procfile
`web: python bot.py`

my runtime.txt
`python-3.7.4`

my requirements.txt

```
astroid==2.2.5
beautifulsoup4==4.7.1
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2019.6.16
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
colorama==0.4.1
Flask==1.1.1
idna==2.8
isort==4.3.21
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mccabe==0.6.1
mysql-connector==2.2.9
oauthlib==3.1.0
pylint==2.3.1
PySocks==1.7.0
requests==2.22.0
requests-oauthlib==1.2.0
selenium==3.141.0
six==1.12.0
soupsieve==1.9.2
tweepy==3.8.0
typed-ast==1.4.0
urllib3==1.25.3
Werkzeug==0.15.5
wrapt==1.11.2
setuptools==1.0
```

When I push for automatic deployment the build log says:

```
-----> Python app detected
 !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.7.3
       Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
-----> Installing python-3.7.4
-----> Installing pip
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

It runs perfectly fine from my computer but I can't me get it working on heroku. 
I've tried:
[Push rejected, failed to compile Python app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22998190/push-rejected-failed-to-compile-python-app)
and it did not work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's no other output besides what you've shown here? Normally there would be a lot of output from `pip` as it tries to install things.

Comment: the only different thing I get when I deploy with heroku git is ```remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.``` and ```! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/my-heroku-app.git```