# When I wanna host my Discord.py bot on Heroku but it gives me this

Tags: heroku, discord.py

I was hosting my discord.py bot on Heroku. I'm trying to upload all my files to Heroku for host the bot but it gives me this:

> remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app. remote:
>   remote:  !     Push failed remote: Verifying deploy... remote: remote:
>   !       Push rejected to rockstarbotxd1. remote: To
>   https://git.heroku.com/rockstarbotxd1.git  ! [remote rejected] master
>   -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/rockstarbotxd1.git'

Comment: Is there a `requirements.txt` at the root folder of your git repository?

Comment: Have you looked at this question (comment section) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62050091/heroku-deployment-error-when-deploying-discord-bot